# Cannot perform a PECL installation

Tags: php, installation, redhat, pecl

I have been trying to do a few PECL installations, but all of them return the same type of error. Something related to timezones? Im running RedHat x86_64 es5.

Attempting to install geoip-1.0.7:

```
root@server [~]# pecl install geoip-1.0.7
downloading geoip-1.0.7.tgz ...
Starting to download geoip-1.0.7.tgz (9,416 bytes)
.....done: 9,416 bytes

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CST/-6.0/no DST' instead in PEAR/Validate.php on line 489

Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CST/-6.0/no DST' instead in /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Validate.php on line 489
3 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/geoip-1.0.7
running: /root/tmp/pear/geoip/configure
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/geoip/configure' failed
```

What is going on? Anyone that could assist please...

Answer (score 1):

from my exeperience, "pecl install packagename" rarely works.

i simply download latest pecl tarball, uncompress, phpize (make sure php is in you path after you compile/install it), ./configure, make, make install,  service php-fpm restart

so for instance, wth the geo-ip pecl package, try

> wget http://pecl.php.net/get/geoip-1.0.8.tgz 
>   cd geoip-1.0.8 
>   phpize 
>   ./configure 
>   make 
>   make install 
>   echo "extenstion=geoip.so" >> /path/to/php.ini
>   sudo service php-fpm|apache restart

EDIT:

if you are missing a developmen package, the compilation error will tell you, and you then

> yum install missingpkg-dev

EDIT:

the specific reason your package appears to not install, is that it is built for a diffent system.  in general, if you compile from source, you will be happier cuz you know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mount -o remount,exec,suid /tmp
mount -o remount,exec,suid /var/tmp
```

Comment: I already have it installed (Package gcc-4.1.2-50.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version). Any other ideas?

Comment: Add output: env | grep CC

Comment: Got the same type of errors when testing "CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.1 pecl install geoip-1.0.7"

Comment: removing the noexec flag on both /tmp and /var/tmp

Comment: You can get compiled package `php-pecl-geoip` from EPEL. Certainly, it's not the solution, but probably you haven't enough time for now to find out what causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone *warnings* (which you should correct by setting a timezone in your php.ini) are completely separate from the actual issue, which is the "error: cannot run C compiled programs" line. You likely don't have `gcc` and/or `make` installed from your package manager. `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` or `yum install gcc make` may do the trick.